# How to animate stretchable muscles?

Tags: animation

I want to create animations of muscles on the human skeleton like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jT-8TUucaRg), especially from 17 seconds in.

How can I create stretchable objects/muscle with Blender? I've seen [x-muscle system](https://blendermarket.com/products/x-muscle-system) but I'm not sure if it's overkill since I basically just need a stretchable material. X-Muscle System creates a character's skin after adding muscles which isn't what I need.

Also does anyone recognise the software used for the linked video? I've seen that little white man character online somewhere but can't remember which software it was for.

Comment: Sorry for the downvotes; you've managed to write a question which uses a lot of terms which are often used in spam posts, which caused a lot of spam flags being [cast automatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291301/295232). We're working on retracting them.

Comment: I had wondered how I got 4 downvotes from 2 views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use IK constraints, expecially with this stretch function:

[image]

Also "Mantain volume" bone constraint can be useful.